# Wrong link AdMob to Firebase to Android app

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I have 1 dev account and 2 apps with admob. In fact one is a copy of the other with another technical id. AdMob works fine with a new unique number on the 2nd app. The 1st one even has been disabled. Now I want to link the 2nd app trough AdMob on Firebase, but Firebase links automatically to the 1st unpublished app. Do you know what the error is?

Comment: Please indicate when you cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/sa7fs1DLS70

Comment: Ha! I recognize you from YT. My apologies - I'm new to this and didn't see my first post I think something went wrong there.

Comment: I hope someone can help me out on this issue - firebase only detects the unpublished app in admob. I need to link the active one - I do not know which 'unique keys' Firebase uses to detect the unpublished one only...

Comment: PlEASE, i'm desperate it doesnt work!!!